# What is a simple and efficient way to compile a function at run time in C++ on Windows/Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, jit

Say I hold a simple, self-contained code for some function in plain C with only **POD** types.

The code is held in an `std::string`.

How can I concretely compile the code at runtime and obtain a **callable object**?

I really need a native, efficient compilation, not anything based on virtual machines.

Thank you.

Comment: C++ is a static pre-compiled language, it has not support for any kind of JIT or runtime [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)).

Comment: There is no simple solution for what you ask. Use some script language like lua instead.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that there is no solution in standard C++. However, there must exist platform specific solutions involving the Windows API and calls to the MS or other compilers. For example, I could write the string as a CPP file on the disk and make a call to compile it with the MS compiler, then load the resulting dll in memory so I can call the function. I was hoping for a in-memory solution but I can live with one that involves the disk. My problem is I don't know how to do all this in practice, what exact sequence of instructions to call to make it happen.

Comment: Essentially this is a tool recommendation question, and those would belong onver on the Software Recommandations SE site. But as the previous comments already note, no point in migrating this.

Comment: Thank you Michal. I know there is no simple solution. Any solution will be complicated and involve platform and compiler specific APIs. This is why I need help.

Comment: It isn't impossible.  But including a C compiler and linker with your program so you can dynamically build a DLL at runtime is neither simple nor efficient.  Just battling the user's anti-malware product is already a major headache.  Do pursue the scripting language approach, a big reason why they exist.

Comment: It sounds like you have figured out one way to do it. But it is a large task, probably much bigger than a single questions worth in OA tbh.

Comment: Construct the source in a string, send that to the compiler toolchain to make a DLL, dynamically load the DLL, call the function.  It's a ton of bother, but some applications do exactly that (e.g., Oracle database) when performance is critical and scripting won't be performant enough.

Comment: Thanks Eljay. This is what I want to do. Could you share any lead on how to do all this in practice?

Comment: What you are asking for is a JIT compiler - AFAIK not a thing in C/C++ as the full language spec does not produce sandboxable code. But! A pure function with a C interface should in theory be compilable. A look online reveals a few C JIT projects, with varying intentions. Consider that graphics/GPU rendering often involves this kind of optimisation, e.g. https://blog.quarkslab.com/easyjit-just-in-time-compilation-for-c.html

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for a JIT compiler, but, ideally without clang or LLVM or any kind of complex installation on all client machines running the software, just a simple dll or exe which I could distribute to clients along with the soft, and with a simple API for compiling code as text (string) and get a callable object (or pointer on a function). Surprisingly, it appears that such thing does not exist...

Answer (score 2):

C++ is generally compiled entirely in advance, as is the case for the Microsoft implementation. To do so you would need a toolchain installed, in which case it is possible to call that as another process, and then do something with the result. If you want to distribute the toolchain, that would be subject to licence terms. You could maybe make a DLL and load that, at the risk of any mistakes in that crashing your process, or make an EXE and interact by other means.

Note that in either case it is difficult to provide security against malicious code, and many other platforms will disallow it.

There are however some C++ **interpreters** around, although I have not used any. These are entirely separate implementations from Microsoft's, which you could look into. Although integrating them is still likely to not be simple.

This is one of the reason C and C++ programs will often use another language for run time scripts, such as Lua, Python, or many others.

Comment: Actually, there are no license terms to agree to for the redistribution of the toolchain - it's just not allowed under any license. Visual Studio comes with an list of the redistributable parts, and the compiler itself is not on it.

Comment: Thank you Fire Lancer. The dll solution would work for me, but what I am really asking is how it would work: what APIs and instructions would result in the run time compilation of the dll, its load in memory and the call to the compiled function. I appreciate there may be licensing difficulties involved, but for the moment I am trying to implement a proof of concept with a technical solution.

Comment: @MSalters I had a feeling that was the case, including professional and win SDK versions as far as direct distribution. But I am less clear on if you got a end user to do it, either directing them to the webpage or maybe downloading and launching the actual installer as long as it is visible to them and they read and accept the terms, or maybe other means so think best left.

Comment: @FireLancer: That is indeed possible, but then you have the problem of locating it, and dealing with the issues when only parts of it are installed (rather common, I think Visual Studio has 100+ optional components)

Comment: Well, the installer does have its own documented command line, although probably more for the "install this on every machine in the office/classroom" use case, and Id guess somewhere in that there is rules on distributing it / auto-downloading.

Comment: @Antonine The same way as you would build your own program in an automated manner. The command lines to invoke directly are documented, or you could generate like a MSBuild solution (again, while VS does this for you, MSBuild is its own documented tool). Manual DLL loading is `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.